# Android disable keyboard key feedback

Tags: android, keyboard, key, feedback

Is there a way to disable the key feedback on the system keyboard?
Like on KeyboardView where you have setPreviewEnabled

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your Manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

For more details you can read [This](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/) & [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I want. When you press and hold a key, a feedback popup of the key appear. That popup I would like to disable